# Check that $A^2=A$

Tags: matrices

I want to check something rather basic, but I can't get it to add up.

Let $A$ be the $2\times2$ matrix.

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        |\alpha|^2&\bar{\alpha}\beta\\
        \alpha\bar{\beta} & |\beta|^2
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

where $$\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$$ and where $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$.

Check that $$A^2=A$$

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        |\alpha|^2&\bar{\alpha}\beta\\
        \alpha\bar{\beta} & |\beta|^2
    \end{pmatrix}^2=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        |\alpha|^2&\bar{\alpha}\beta\\
        \alpha\bar{\beta} & |\beta|^2
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        |\alpha|^4+\alpha\bar{\beta}\beta\bar{\alpha}&\bar{\alpha}\beta|\alpha|^2+\bar{\alpha}\beta|\beta|^2\\
        \alpha\bar{\beta}|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\alpha\bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha}\beta\bar{\beta}\alpha+|\beta|^4
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^2\ne A$$

But is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Why do we have $|\alpha|^4=|\alpha|^2$? And what do you mean with "everything about complex matrices actually confirms that $A^2=A$"?

Comment: Take $\alpha=\beta=1$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta$ supposed to satisfy $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$?

Comment: @prets Yes, sorry I forgot to add that.

Comment: OK, in that case just factor out $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2$ from each entry in $A^2$. Note that $\alpha \overline \alpha = |\alpha|^2$ and similar for $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks, that is great!

Comment: Though I voted to close my own question, I see that it still remains largely unanswered, except for Prets answer. For instance, how can $ |\alpha|^4+\alpha\bar{\beta}\beta\bar{\alpha}=|\alpha|^2$

Comment: Factor out $| \alpha |^2$ (using my hint about conjugates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is equal to
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}
$$
Squaring this, and exploiting associativity of matrix multiplication, we get
$$
A^2=\left(\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
=\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\right)\times\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}\\
=(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)\begin{bmatrix}\bar\alpha\\\bar\beta\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix} = A
$$

(Yes, that's a $1\times 1$ matrix in the middle of the third line, turned into a scalar factor on the fourth line.)

Comment: Thanks, this is monstruous, and I see your steps completely clearly.

Comment: No problem Arthur, I see your method now, so I will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The condition $A^2= A$ implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are included in $\{0,1\},$ while the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $t(t-|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2).$

So it is easy to see your matrix $A$ in general cannot satisfy $A^2 = A.$

Comment: More explicitly, the matrix with every entry equal to $1$ ($\alpha=\beta=1$) certainly does not satisfy $A^2=A$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that

$A^2=A \iff \alpha = \beta =0 $ or $| \alpha|^2+ | \beta|^2=1.$